# Ferment and naturally carbonate in a keg

Tags: fermentation

want to try to ferment under the pressure for the first time.,just to clear few things, please correct me if I’m about to do something wrong.

1. Cool down the wort in a kettle.
2. Transfer to the keg.
3. Adjust pressure relief valve,let the pressure build to 15 psi,and keep it at 15 psi till fermentation will complete.
4. Cool down and drink carbonated beer?
   The questions are,is 10 days of primary fermentation will be enough to carbonate the beer under 15-20 psi?
   If I ferment under lower psi let’s say 5 can I use priming sugar and bottle it with out creating bottle bombs, cos there will be already CO2 in the beer.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

That basically how it's done. However what you may have overlooked is what to do about the yeast trub.

I've seen conversion kits for corny kegs that have a floating pick up tube so this process can be fermented and poured from the same keg without pouring a gallon of trub out first.

A friend naturaly carbonates in his spedials he's found that setting the relief to 8psi during most of the fermentation then to 15psi after most fermentation is complete gives him better results. **Yeast can get stressed and have poor health if the cO2 and pressure increases too fast.** he then racks the carbonated fined beer to corny kegs for serving.

Comment: Thank you for reply, actually I changed my mind after your comment ,I was planning to make raspberry RIS 10 little batch in 10.5 little keg,so it’s going to be a problem with the trub,so I m going to ferment it normally in the fermenter.Just one more question, do you remember where did you see those conversion kits I want to make one or to buy one.Once more thank you.

Comment: @Iacovlev I can't at the moment.. What I saw may have just been proto type diagram. I think they were having issue with finding a flexible tube that wouldn't kink or collapse under serving pressure. I've seen one in a Mr Beer style kit, but the fermenter wasn't as narrow as a corny.

Comment: Thank you,I think I found something similar.          https://www.ibrew.com.au/products/clear-beer-draught-system.   Cheers.

Comment: @Iacovlev well I opened up Zymurgy today to see an ad for what I saw long ago. Idk if it's the same maker but does look like a good solution. http://www.clearbeerdraughtsystem.com